# How to authorize when sending email with Mailgun?

Tags: postman, mailgun

I would like to send email with Mailgun via Postman. I write my `Private API key` in all different way in the `Authorization` section in Postman. But it always refuse me, got a HTTP `401`.

What is wrong?

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

I tried send via CURL as tutorial suggest, but is fails also:

https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/quickstart-sending.html#send-via-api

```
kukodajanos@Kukoda-MacBook-Pro-2 ~ % curl -s --user 'api:b3c5...' \
    https://api.mailgun.net/v3/mg.tiket.hu/messages \
    -F from='janosontech@gmail.com' \
    -F to=kukodajanos@icloud.com \
    -F subject='Hello' \
    -F text='Testing some Mailgun awesomeness!'
Forbidden%
```

Comment: Mind posting the `tsconfig.json` file?

Comment: Are you developing on windows, mac, or Linux? It can be a case-sensitive issue.

Comment: Did you make sure that the API key and domain name (`mg.tiket.hu`) are correct?

Comment: Maybe you should use the domain https://api.eu.mailgun.net/ instead of https://api.mailgun.net/  I noticed you are in Budapest. I had the same issue, and the following change solved my problem.

Comment: On Windows, replacing single quote ' with double quote " and putting everything on the same line was necessary in my experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic authentication (as in your first screenshot) should work. (Also make sure, you don't have any spaces, newlines or other wrong characters included in your token)

Are you using your primary API key or a sending key specifically for that domain? If the first, try creating a sending key for you domain. If the latter, try recreating the key.